# How to query two values in different columns from different dates?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to query a `daily_price` table by the following logic:

*today's close > today's open* **and** *today's close > yesterdays high*

The desired output is returning all rows from today that meet the criteria. With the below example, and assuming today is 2022-08-31, the query would return ACR but not NBI because the logic matches (i.e. 2022-08-31 close > 2022-08-31 open **and** 2022-08-31 close > 2022-08-30 high).

`daily_price` example:

| symbol | date | open | high | low | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACR | 2022-08-30 | 0.061 | 0.063 | 0.06 | 0.06 |
| ACR | 2022-08-31 | 0.066 | 0.07 | 0.066 | 0.07 |
| NBI | 2022-08-30 | 1.52 | 1.52 | 1.51 | 1.52 |
| NBI | 2022-08-31 | 1.51 | 1.52 | 1.505 | 1.515 |

I tried this query with no luck:

```
SELECT * 
FROM daily_price 
WHERE close > open
AND date = '2022-08-31' 
AND (SELECT close FROM daily_price WHERE date = '2022-08-31') > (SELECT high FROM daily_price WHERE date = '2022-08-30')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `lag` to compare today's *close* with yesterday's *high* and filtering by `date`.

```
select  symbol  
       ,date    
       ,open    
       ,high    
       ,low 
       ,close
from    (
        select *
              ,lag(high)    over (partition by symbol order by date)      as pre
        from   t
        ) t

where   close > pre 
  and   close > open 
  and   date = '2022-08-31'
```

| symbol | date | open | high | low | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACR | 2022-08-31 | 0.066 | 0.07 | 0.066 | 0.07 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=8e83ab2014aec44bb8dc93625211a998&hide=1)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Exists` with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
Select T.symbol, T.date_, T.open, T.high, T.low, T.close 
From daily_price T
Where T.close > T.open And
Exists (Select 1 From daily_price D 
        Where D.symbol=T.symbol And 
              D.date_=Date(T.date_, '-1 day') And 
              D.high < T.close)
```

See a demo [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=8a8a00a3466c368923131631d0fc103d).